# Unable to use new apple id in app store on iPhone 4 IOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, apple-id, iphone

My parents just gave me their old iPhone 4 and I cannot get my Apple ID to work correctly.here is what I did:

1. Reset all content and settings
2. Selected English, United States, wifi, enabled location, and set up as new iPhone
3. Signed in with my Apple ID (that I had just created during last reset) ([username].icloud.com)
4. Agreed to terms and conditions
5. Clicked use iCloud, and declined find my iPhone
6. Set passcode
   7 clicked set up keychain later
7. Attempted to download app (Bible gateway)
8. Clicked sign in with Apple ID
9. A message that says "This Apple Id has not yet been used in iTunes store. Tap review to sign in, then review your account information." Pops up (I clicked review)
10. I agreed to terms of conditions
11. Entered password and security question
12. Another red message said "this email address i is not available for use as an apple I'd. You may already have an Apple ID associated with this address. Please try again or sign in using your existing apple Id. New password must not have been used in the past year."
13. Then I tried [username]@mac.com
14. Popup message says "email is already an apple I'd. Tap continue to sign in..." Etc
15. Clicked use existing apple I'd
16. Entered username and password
17. Said it was already an apple I'd
18. Hit back
19. Hit next again and filled out billing info
20. Hot next and red message said email address is already an apple Id

I don't know what to do anymore. Help me please!

Comment: Give us a call at Apple Support 1-800-MY-APPLE and we will take a look at the account to get you set up.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I fixed it  I think my Gmail that I used was invalid/unverified

Comment: Good catch. Congrats